# AngularJS update data in ng-repeat from http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I searched for solution but I didn't found an answer. What is my problem, on my category view I have init function which makes http request and get all category from database. I use that records and make ng-repeat. But when I open modal with form to make new category I can't update that ng-repeat view when modal close and see new category. I organize my controller, service and view in this way:

view

```
<div class="row main-body no-padding" ng-init="adminCtr.initCategory()">

    <div class="col-lg-4 margin-bottom-20" ng-repeat="category in adminCtr.allCategories">
        <div class="header-panel">
            <span class="category-headline">{{category.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main-form">
            {{category.id_cat}}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

controller:

```
function addCategory() {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/modal/addCategory.html',
            clickOutsideToClose: false,
            controller: 'adminController',
            controllerAs: 'adminCtr'
        });
    }

    function initCategory() {
        adminService.initCategory().then(function (data) {
            vm.allCategories = data.categories;
        })
    }

    function createCategory(category) {
        adminService.createCategory(category).then(function (data) {
            if(data.success == false) {
                vm.categoryError = data.error;
            } else {
                vm.categoryError = '';
                cancelModal();
                initCategory();
                $location.path('/admin/category');
                $timeout(function () {
                    $mdToast.show(
                        $mdToast.simple()
                            .textContent('Kategorija je uspešno kreirana')
                            .position('top right')
                            .theme("success-toast")
                            .hideDelay(5000)
                    );
                }, 500);
            }
        })
    }

    function cancelModal() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    }
```

service:

```
function createCategory(category) {
        return $http.post('api/admin/createCategory', {
            category: category,
            idUser: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.idUser,
            token: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.token
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    function initCategory() {
        return $http.post('api/admin/getAllCategories', {
            idUser: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.idUser,
            token: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.token
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
```

I tried to call again init function to update vm.allCategories but without any success.

Does any know some solution?

P.S. I tried with $scope.apply() but I got error, btw I use angular 1.6.2.

Comment: Can you create a minimal working plnkr/jsbin/jsfiddle ? Read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does data.category contains? can you show us the sample array/object format ?

Comment: {"categories":[{"id_cat":"1","name":"fgfdgfd"},{"id_cat":"2","name":"dfgfdgdf"},{"id_cat":"3","name":"dfgfdgdffdgdfg"},{"id_cat":"4","name":"dfgfdgdfg"},{"id_cat":"5","name":"dfdsfsdfsdfsd"},{"id_cat":"6","name":"sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsd"},{"id_cat":"7","name":"dfgfdgfgfgfdgdf"}],"success":true}

Comment: Just name and id category

Comment: Your vm.allCategories is updating in js but it is not getting reflected in UI?

Comment: exactly and I want to avoid to refresh page

Comment: You can use track by to do that. see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42864912/3543808)

Answer (score 0):

in the service remove the promise. you are caching the response in the controller using promise. So need to add a promise in the service also.

```
 function initCategory() {
        return $http.post('api/admin/getAllCategories', {
            idUser: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.idUser,
            token: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.token
        }) 
  }
```

in the controller update like this

```
function initCategory() {
        adminService.initCategory().then(function (res) {
            vm.allCategories = res.data.categories; // in the response data comes inside data property. 
        })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, same result, I should refresh page to see new added category

Comment: did you console `vm.allCategories`

Comment: Yes, in function initCategory and get updated records but view stays same

Comment: after `vm.allCategories = res.data.categories;` line add `$scope.$apply()` and try it

Comment: I got error $digest already in progress, after version I think 1.4 that doesn't  work

Comment: no if the digest is already running then the data should be bind

Comment: try vm.allCategories.length=0; vm.allCategories.concat(res.data.categories);

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML template like below:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 margin-bottom-20" ng-repeat="category in adminCtr.allCategories track by category.id_cat">
```

and your JS

```
function initCategory() {
    adminService.initCategory().then(function(data) {
        $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
            vm.allCategories = data.categories;
        });
    })
}
```

## Demo

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  var a = [{
    "id_cat": "1",
    "name": "fgfdgfd"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "2",
    "name": "dfgfdgdf"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "3",
    "name": "dfgfdgdffdgdfg"
  }];
  var b = [{
    "id_cat": "1",
    "name": "fgfdgfd"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "2",
    "name": "dfgfdgdf"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "3",
    "name": "dfgfdgdffdgdfg"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "4",
    "name": "dfgfdgdfg"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "5",
    "name": "dfdsfsdfsdfsd"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "6",
    "name": "sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsd"
  }, {
    "id_cat": "7",
    "name": "dfgfdgfgfgfdgdf"
  }];
  vm.allCategories = a;

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      vm.allCategories = b;
    });

  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="category in vm.allCategories track by category.id_cat">
    {{category.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, still is same, I do need to refresh page to see results

Comment: I got this error $scope.$safeApply is not a function

Comment: try with `$scope.$evalAsync`

Comment: Now I don't get record in view even after refresh page

Comment: Can I somehow just refresh particular div on particular side?

Comment: I get undefined for vm.allCategories

Comment: I get categories in console but again view on page stays the same. Can I refresh div on that page, not all page just one div?

Comment: @Sasa no you can't and it is an anti pattern

Comment: Only solution is to reload all page

Comment: @Sasa See the updated answer for code snippet. There is nothing wrong with $evalAsync. try to debug the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138355/discussion-between-sasa-and-gangadhar-jannu).

Comment: At the end I decide to make location path on blank page and then return on category view, isn't the best but is better then reload.